# Automate this steps for multiple files with python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, multiple-columns, glob

I am working with python for a project in which I need to convert the rows (LGA, Dates, Precipitation) to columns for each of over 770 files in the same directory. Then merge the result for each file into one single csv file. I am working with a large daily weather data for 774 local government areas over 4 years. I am trying to automate the steps below using the code below (perhaps with a for loop). Is there a way I can go around it?

Thanks!

```
kaduna_south = pd.read_csv("/Users/location_weather/Kaduna South.csv",
                             parse_dates = ["Date"])

kaduna_south['LGA'].fillna(value = ' ', inplace=True)

kaduna_south = kaduna_south.pivot(index=['LGA'], columns='Date',values=['Precip'])

kaduna_south.columns = kaduna_south.columns.droplevel()

kaduna_south = kaduna_south.rename_axis(None,axis=1)

kaduna_south = kaduna_south.reset_index()

kaduna_south = kaduna_south.drop(labels=[1], axis=0)

kaduna_south.loc[:, 'LGA'] = 'KADUNA SOUTH'

kaduna_south.fillna(value = '0.0', inplace=True)

weather_list = pd.concat([kubau, gassol, adavi, kaduna_south, jalingo, ardo_kola, makarfi, bali, kauru, igabi, doguwa, iseyin, abeokuta_north,
                          osogbo, ede_south, ijebu_north, emure, soba, karim_lamido, nsukka, akinyele],
                         ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What is the larger goal of your project? What portion of the project are you trying to automate? And if there is additional code that is relevant to the question, can you provide that as well?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to convert the rows (LGA, Dates, Precipitation) to columns for each of the files. Then merge the result together into one single file. I am working with a large daily weather data for 774 local government areas over 4 years.

Answer (score 2):

Put your dataframe processing code in a function and call it on each file.

```
def process_weather_data(lga):
    df = pd.read_csv(f"/Users/location_weather/{lga}.csv")
    df['LGA'].fillna(value = ' ', inplace=True)
    df = df.pivot(index=['LGA'], columns='Date',values=['Precip'])
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    df = df.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.drop(labels=[1], axis=0)
    df.loc[:, 'LGA'] = lga
    df.fillna(value = '0.0', inplace=True)
    return df

lgas = ["Kaduna South", "Kubau", "Gassol"] # etc.
weather_list = pd.concat([process_weather_data(lga) for lga in lgas], ignore_index=True)
```

You might be able to simplify this by applying the changes to the concatenated `weather_list` all at once rather than on each individual dataframe, but it is difficult to know if you can do that or not without seeing the form your CSV files are in.

EDIT: Based on your comment about the format of the CSV you can probably simplify this to:

```
lgas = ["Kaduna South", "Kubau", "Gassol"] # etc
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f"/Users/location_weather/{lga}.csv") for lga in lgas])
weather_list = df \
    .assign(LGA=df["LGA"].ffill()) \
    .pivot(index='LGA', columns='Date',values='Precip') \
    .fillna(value='0.0')
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  You really don't know how happy this makes me feel right now. I am a new user so I am not able to attach screenshots yet. Basically, I am trying to  am trying to convert the rows (LGA, Dates, Precipitation) to columns for each of the files. Then merge the result together into one single file. I am working with a large daily weather data for 774 local government areas over 4 years.

Comment: @AdedayoAbdullahi Instead of a screenshot you could copy paste in the first 3 lines of one of the CSVs as text.

Comment: LGA Date Precip
Kaduna South 1/1/14 0
 1/2/14 0
 1/3/14 0
 1/4/14 0
 1/5/14 0.                                                                                                              That's the structure of the original csv files I am trying to convert and automate. I have 1462 rows in each column. The new format will be like this with each date having precipitation values:          LGA 2014-01-01 00:00:00 2014-01-02 00:00:00 2014-01-03 00:00:00 2014-01-04 00:00:00 2014-01-05 00:00:00.              Does this make better sense? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I am getting this error when I run the updated code:  NameError: name 'lgas' is not defined

Comment: You need to define `lgas` with a list of the LGA names as the are used in the CSV filenames, as shown in the first solution

Comment: I did as suggested with the second solution. This what was returned:    ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape